# Jquery selection of multiple input without using ids

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code like this:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="#first">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="#second">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="#third">

        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

If I want to get each input's text i could simply use jquery id selection (`$('first).text()`)
Since I know there are tons of way to select dom elements, is there a nice way to select each one of them not using the id selector?

Comment: Try `$("input[type=text]")`, also it should be `id="first"` and not `id="#first"`. Also it should be `$('f#irst).text()` and not `$('first).text()`

Comment: Or using class name `$('.form-control')`

Comment: Thanks for the remark!

Answer (score 1):

Use `$("input[type=text]")` **Carsten** suggested in the comments. (also watch his hints according your syntax)

If you want to work with those elements (for example validating) you can use the `.each()` function in jquery and work with $(this):

```
$("input[type=text]").each(function( index ) {
  var test = $(this).val();
});
```

Here some other possibilities to select those inputs:

**class**

give them all the same class and make the selector like this `$(".yourClass")`

**parent**

give the container of all those inputs that you want to select a specific class `$(".yourContainerClass input")` or more precise `$(".yourContainerClass input[type=text]")`

**attributes**

like `type` you have access to every attribut of the input field like this: `$("[attribute='value']")` this could be `name` `value` or watherver you like

here you have an overview of the attribute selectors according to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp):

- **[attribute]** - ex. $("[href]") - All elements with a href attribute
- **[attribute!=value]** - ex. $("[href!='default.htm']") - All elements with a href attribute value not equal to "default.htm"
- **[attribute$=value]** - ex. $("[href$='.jpg']") - All elements with a href attribute value ending with ".jpg"
- **[attribute|=value]** - ex- $("[title|='Tomorrow']") - All elements with a title attribute value equal to 'Tomorrow', or starting with 'Tomorrow' followed by a hyphen
- **[attribute^=value]** - ex. $("[title^='Tom']") - All elements with a title attribute value starting with "Tom"
- **[attribute~=value]** - ex. $("[title~='hello']") - All elements with a title attribute value containing the specific word "hello"
- **[attribute*=value]** - ex. $("[title*='hello']") - All elements with a title attribute value containing the word "hello"